# Editing paragraphs field settings returns 404 with php development server

Tags: 9, paragraphs

I have this strange behaviour on my local drupal9 instance. I start it in the `web` folder with the build in php development server: `php -S localhost:8000`

Now if I try to edit any paragraphs field, eg. `/admin/structure/paragraphs_type/manual_news/fields/paragraph.manual_news.field_news_entries`

`[Fri Aug 13 12:47:39 2021] 127.0.0.1:55544 [404]: POST /admin/structure/paragraphs_type/manual_news/fields/paragraph.manual_news.field_news_entries - No such file or directory`

I get a 404 from the server. If it runs on a real webserver, it works.

Anybody knows how to debug / fix this?

I also opened https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs/issues/3228039 for this issue.

Comment: It appears to be a drupal core issue thou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean URLs aren't supported when `php -S` is used to run the Drupal site because clean URLs require the .htaccess file or another file used from Nginx, which PHP doesn't use.

Either you don't use clean URLs (for example, /index.php?q=admin/structure/paragraphs_type/manual_news/fields/paragraph.manual_news.field_news_entries), or you start the server with `php -S localhost:8888 .ht.router.php`, where [.ht.router.php](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/9.2.x/.ht.router.php) is a file that comes with Drupal 9. The router script also works around a bug in PHP, reported in [If the trailing path that follows a script contains a dot PATH_INFO is not set](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61286).

Comment: Works like a charm - thx man, this one was haunting me for quite some years already!